# App crash: when writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum using ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

We are making a chat app and for video thumbnail we use the following code. But it crashes in random cases.

```
NSArray *arrjid = [jid componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *strdate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *strname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_file.mov",arrjid[0],strdate];
NSString *videoPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strname];
[videoData writeToFile:videoPath atomically:YES];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoPath])
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

Every time it crashes on the `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` line and it gives only "bad access error".

Does anyone have an idea related to this?

Comment: Any error message in console?

Comment: Did u check your iOS Deployment target?  writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock: is only avaiable from ios 4.0-9.0

Use PHPhotoLibrary framework instead

Comment: Hello jabson
I tried to using PHPhotoLibrary library but not generate a thumbnail of the video that's why I used depicted ALAssetsLibrary method.
i deployment target is iOS 10.0.
so if you have any idea for generating thumbnails of HTTP URL of video then please help me.

Comment: Hello Larme,not display error message only give bad access.we are enable zombie object but not display any kind of message.

Comment: I have update my answer, you can use AVAssetImageGenerator class to generate thumbnail from video.
there is no way to generate thumbnail from http url video should be in iPhone storage

Comment: Hello jabson
 your code is working but how to save the video in particular album?.we created album "videosAPP" but video does not save in album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALAssetsLibrary library method writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock: is deprecated, you can use PHPhotoLibrary instead.

try this

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL: yourVideoURlHere];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        //Do Something   
    }
}];
```

Also check if you have Photo Library usage description in info plist with following key

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
```

**UPDATE**

For fetching thumbnail from video you can use AVAssetImageGenerator class from AVFoundation framework

```
- (UIImage *) thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:(NSURL *) contentURL {
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:contentURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);

    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: Hello jabson your code is working but how to save the video in particular album?.we created album "videosAPP" but video does not save in album.

Comment: Hi, This is another question, next time try to create another one.
please see first answer of the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249135/save-a-photo-to-custom-album-in-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permission to save to the photo gallery.

Import the Photos class:

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

Then check for Photo Library Authorization

```
PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];

if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    //OK to save your video
    [self ContinueDownload];
}
else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    // Access has been denied.
    [self ShowAlert];
}
else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

    // Access has not been determined.
    [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {

        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
             //OK to save your video
            [self ContinueDownload];
        }
        else {
            // Access has been denied.
            [self ShowAlert];
        }
    }];
}
else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
    // Restricted access
}

//Show an alert if access is denied
-(void)ShowAlert {
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Gallery Access denied"
                                 message:@"You can grant access in\nSettings/Privacy/Photos\nif you change your mind."
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];



    UIAlertAction* OKButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                   //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];

    [alert addAction:OKButton];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```